# Angular2 How to get data using query params from dropdown selection

Tags: angular, http, get, routes

Hi I want to use queryParams to get data from the server.

Currently I've got selection with ngFor options and after I choose an option,

I'd like to store it somehow and want the component to redirect to another routes (appended with queryParams) that could get corresponding data from the server based on the selection.

I figured there should be service to get data from,
2 components with templates, one to display selections, 
the other to use the aforementioned service to execute http get request.

But I have no idea how to proceed these.

Below is my code I currently have.

html file

```
 <select [(ngModel)]="selected_region"> 
  <option (click)="onSelect0()" *ngFor="let region of regions">
  {{region.areaName}}
  </option>
 </select>
```

component

```
onSelect0() {
    this.selected_region = //I don't know what to add here.
  }

onSubmit() {
     this.router.navigate(['../teacherlist']);
  }
```

And in the teacherlist component..

```
constructor(
        private _location: Location,
        private searchTeacher: SearchTeacherService) { }

    ngOnInit():void { 
        this.searchTeacher.getTeachers() //I think I should add queryParams here but I don't know how
    }
```

Please HELP!

Comment: https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/query_params.html

Comment: click `onSelect0()` do you want which region is selected OR does anything its related with routers params i.e you want to select the region according to navigated router url ????

Comment: Note: `onSelect0` method is not required because you already have used `[(ngModel)]` which will update your `selected_region` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Define your router as follows :

```
{ path: '../teacherlist/:id', component: TeacherListComponent }
```

Send params as follows:

```
this.router.navigate(['../teacherlist', this.selected_region]);
```

Receive as follows (in TeacherListComponent):

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params
    // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
    .switchMap((params: Params) => this.searchTeacher.getTeachers(+params['id']))
    .subscribe((hero: Hero) => this.hero = hero);
}
```